# Как сохранить и передать данные при закрытии формы?

Tags: swift

Начал изучать swift, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть два View – **TreningEditor** и **CategoryEditor**. В **TreningEditor**, при нажатии на кнопку “**Add Trening**”  происходит вызов *View* **CategoryEditor**, где сохраняются необходимые данные для *$trening.catTrening*, но при закрытие формы, данные не сохраняются и цикл  ForEach($trening.catTrening) пустой

Как сохранить и передать данные при закрытии формы?

```
struct TreningEditor: View {
        @Binding var trening: TreningItem
        @State var isNew = false
        @State var isNewCat = false
        
        @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
        @FocusState var focusedExercise: Item?
        @FocusState var focusedExerciseList: Exercise?
        @State private var isPickingSymbol = false
        
        @State private var isAddingNewCategory = false
        @State private var newCategory = Item()
        
        var body: some View {
         
                List {
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            isPickingSymbol.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: trening.symbol)
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(trening.color))
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                        
                        TextField("New Trening", text: $trening.treningName)
                            .font(.title2)
                        
                        Button {
                            isPickingSymbol.toggle()
                        }
                    label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        } .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                    
                    DatePicker("Date", selection: $trening.date)
                        .labelsHidden()
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    
                    Text("Exercises")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    ForEach($trening.catTrening)
                    { 
                        $item in Text("Test Trening: \(item.category)")
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        trening.catTrening.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                    })
                    
                    Button {
                        isNewCat = true
                        CategoryEditor(trening: $newCategory, isNewCat: isNewCat)
           trening.catTrening.append(newCategory)
    
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                            Text("Add Trening")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isNewCat) {
                       // isNewCat = true
                        CategoryEditor(trening: $newCategory, isNewCat: isNewCat)
                   }
                }
            
    #if os(iOS)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    #endif
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPickingSymbol) {
                SymbolPicker(trening: $trening)
            }
        }
    }
```

==

```
struct CategoryEditor: View {
    @Binding var trening: Item
    @State var isNewCat = false
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @FocusState var focusedExercise: Exercise?
    @State private var isPickingSymbol = false
    
    @State private var isAddingNewCategory = false
    @State private var newCategory = Item()
    
    @State var category: String = "Ноги"
     var categoryList = ["Руки","Ноги"]
    
     @State var tag: String = "Не выбрано"
     var tagList = ["Не выбрано","Икры","Пресс", "Брасс"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView
        {
            List {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("New Category")
                }
                .padding(.top, 5)
                
                Picker(selection: $category, label: Text("Тренируем"))
                {
                    ForEach(categoryList, id: \.self)
                    {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                    
                }  .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                
                Picker(selection: $tag, label: Text("Тег"))
                {
                    ForEach(tagList, id: \.self)
                    {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                    
                }  .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                
                Text("Exercises")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                ForEach($trening.exercise)
                { 
                 $item in  ExerciseAddRow(exercise: $item, focusedExercise: $focusedExercise, exerciseSelect: "Не выбрано", exerciseSelectList: ["Не выбрано","Жим ногами"])
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    trening.exercise.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                })
                
                Button {
                    let newExercise = Exercise(exerciseName: "", 
                                               set: 0, rep: 0, 
                                               link: "",
                                               exerciseCat: "",
                                               isNew: true  )
                    
                    trening.exercise.append(newExercise)
                    focusedExercise = newExercise
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                        Text("Add Exercise")
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            }
            
#if os(iOS)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
#endif
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPickingSymbol) {
                // SymbolPicker(trening: $trening)
            }.toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction){
                    Button("Cancel", action: {dismiss()}).foregroundColor(Color(trening.color))
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction){
                    Button("Save", action: {}).foregroundColor(Color(trening.color))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```